# Sorted TODO list with :sort n and letters

Tags: sort

Let's say I have ordered TODO list with priorities, sorted already with `:sort n` similar to :

```
1. shopping
3. cooking.
D 5. car repair.
D 11. tap fix.
12. project start
```

`D` means done.

I am using `:sort n` function to sort this list, but all done (`D`) things should go at the end of list. Result should be like this:

```
1. shopping
3. cooking
12. project start. 
D 5. car repair. 
D 11. tap fix.
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>td :sort n<CR>:sort n /[D]/<CR>
```

Then in Normal mode, you can type <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (assuming you haven't changed the default leader key to something else) to sort your to-do list.

Comment: this solution gives me error message when I type it in normal mode: E10: \ should be followed by /,? or &

Comment: Did you type in `:sort n`, Enter, `:sort n /[D]/`, Enter exactly? If you add my line above exactly to `.vimrc`, it can be done in a couple keystrokes rather than typing out both lines.

Comment: yea, it is working, very fast solution :)

Answer (score 3):

If your list is already sorted with `:sort n`, you can move the done `D` items to the bottom of the list with a global command:

```
:g/^D/m$
```

This works through the file from top to bottom, moving each line that starts with a D. Because the `D` lines are already sorted when you run the command, they remain sorted after it.

If you want to perform both steps in a single go, you could use a mapping similar to the one [suggested by Kevin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15184/343) or perhaps a custom command:

```
" Run this command with :TodoSort
:command! TodoSort sort n | g/^D/m$
```